# Converting encoding from unknown-8bit to us-ascii not supported

Tags: encoding, terminal, iconv

I am trying to convert from unknown-8bit to us-ascii by using iconv. I have
    `$ iconv -f unknown-8bit -t us-ascii file.txt > file1.txt`

It shows an error message.

```
iconv: conversion from `unknown-8bit' is not supported
Try `iconv --help' or `iconv --usage' for more information.
```

Is there an alternative to conduct the conversion? Thank you!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `cat -v`, e.g.,

```
cat -v file.txt > file1.txt
```

On most platforms, that will give an ASCII file.

Comment: Accentuated characters (é, è, ê, ...) are lost in the new file. Is there a way keep them?

Comment: Those aren't ASCII.  In a quick-test, I'm seeing those become `M-i, M-h, M-j, ...`, which is expected.

Comment: @ThomasDickey why is this encoding expected and do you have a list of what they represent?

Comment: The accented characters are coded in the range 160-255, while US-ASCII is only defined for (printable) 32-126, so any program that handles the conversion will use some workaround to represent the out-of-range codes.  The "M" denotes meta, which is used for instance in [terminfo](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous) and curses.  iconv came "later", so it didn't originate the "M".

Answer (score 1):

with accents, you can set it in vim as mentioned in this post: [Set encoding and fileencoding to utf-8 in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507777/set-encoding-and-fileencoding-to-utf-8-in-vim)

In my case, I have issue on '…', '−' and '-', I open the file under vim, correct issues and run in vim

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
```

then save it and my file is utf-8 encoded!