# How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?

Tags: linux, file, command-line, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a file in UTF-8 encoding with BOM and want to remove the BOM. Are there any linux command-line tools to remove the BOM from the file?

```
$ file test.xml
test.xml:  XML 1.0 document, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A BOM is Unicode codepoint U+FEFF; the UTF-8 encoding consists of the three hex values 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF.

With bash, you can create a UTF-8 BOM with the `$''` special quoting form, which implements Unicode escapes: `$'\uFEFF'`. So with bash, a reliable way of removing a UTF-8 BOM from the beginning of a text file would be:

```
sed -i $'1s/^\uFEFF//' file.txt
```

This will leave the file unchanged if it does not start with a UTF-8 BOM, and otherwise remove the BOM.

If you are using some other shell, you might find that `"$(printf '\ufeff')"` produces the BOM character (that works with `zsh` as well as any shell without a `printf` builtin, provided that `/usr/bin/printf` is the Gnu version ), but if you want a Posix-compatible version you could use:

```
sed "$(printf '1s/^\357\273\277//')" file.txt
```

(The `-i` in-place edit flag is also a Gnu extension; this version writes the possibly-modified file to stdout.)

Comment: creating the BOM with bash on windows didn't seem to work, this did https://stackoverflow.com/a/3622153/1507124

Comment: Funny, my source file came from a Windows environment, so I was scratching my head why bash read "${line:0:1}" is returning an empty character until I used "od -c filename.txt" to check wether it has BOM "357 273 277" and it did.

Answer (score 56):

#### Using VIM

1. Open file in VIM:

   ```
    vi text.xml
   ```
2. Remove BOM encoding:

   ```
    :set nobomb
   ```
3. Save and quit:

   ```
    :wq
   ```

---

For a non-interactive solution, try the following command line:

```sh
vi -c ":set nobomb" -c ":wq" text.xml
```

That should remove the BOM, save the file and quit, all from the command line.

Comment: Is there a way to make vim do that non-interactively? OP asked for a "command line" solution.

Comment: @DoktorJ If you find out, make sure to post a comment back here for others.

Comment: It didn't work at all for me, because vim was expecting the wrong encoding.  Fix is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507777/set-encoding-and-fileencoding-to-utf-8-in-vim  (Perhaps only the file encoding needs to be set, but I set both, and I did it in my .vimrc)

Comment: @DoktorJ Try using `-c` flag in `vi`, like: `vi -c ":set nobomb" -c ":wq" text.xml`. That should remove the BOM, save the file and quit all from the command line.

Answer (score 18):

Well, just dealt with this today and my preferred way was dos2unix:

**dos2unix** will remove BOM and also take care of other idiosyncrasies from other SOs:

```
$ sudo apt install dos2unix
$ dos2unix test.xml
```

It's also possible to remove BOM only (-r, --remove-bom):

```
$ dos2unix -r test.xml
```

**Note:** tested with dos2unix 7.3.4

Comment: A SuSE user reports that their version of `dos2unix` does not do this. Not sure what the version number might be or if they are even from the same source.

Comment: (I tried to repro just now with the `opensuse/archive` Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/opensuse/archive but that gives me `dos2unix` 7.3.4 which works just as advertised in this answer. Probably the OpenSUSE version I got was not ancient enough. `head -n 2 /etc/os-release` gets me `NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="42.3"`)

Comment: @tripleee : well .. I'm glad you made it and also glad I posted a very specific version in my answer :-)

Comment: The above answer (using sed) doesn't work on ZSH because the need for inline. This worked on a folder of 760 files in one command thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**IF** you are certain that a given file starts with a BOM, then it is possible to remove the BOM from a file with the `tail` command:

```
tail --bytes=+4 withBOM.txt > withoutBOM.txt
```

Comment: This should only be done if you *know* that the file begins with a UTF-8 encoded BOM. It's not a good idea as a general suggestion, because if the file did not begin with a BOM, or if the file was UTF-16 (or any other encoding) this will destroy the first few meaningful characters of the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on a bulk of files, by improving Reginaldo Santos's answers,  there is a quick way:

```sh
find . -name "*.java" | grep java$ | xargs -n 1 dos2unix
```

Comment: What's with the `grep`? You have already selected only files whose names end with `.java` in the `find` command's `-name` option argument.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Pinter's answer works correctly on mac so I wrote a script that removes the BOM from all files in a given folder, see [here](https://github.com/LudvigWesterdahl/Scripts/blob/master/rmbom).

It can be used like follows:

Remove BOM from all files in current directory: `rmbom .`

Print all files with a BOM in the current directory: `rmbom . -a`

Only remove BOM from all files in current directory with extension txt or cs: `rmbom . -e txt -e cs`