# How to concat string in gnu-parallel?

Tags: string, shell, gnu-parallel

I try to realize a tiny function that is to read  users name from **fastalist ** file and to parallely create **name.txt**.  But the spliced filenames confused me.

As shown in the below, the first one name is '1pazA' but the output is '.txtA'. It is likely the first 3 letters are replaced. However, for the second out is right.

```
# cmd
cat BuildFeatures/example/fastalist | parallel -j 5 echo {}.txt
# out
.txtA
T0968s1.txt

# fastalist file content
1pazA
T0968s1
```

I expect to get the right spliced string.

Comment: Looks to me like an encoding issue. I can reproduce it when `fastalist` is saved as a csv file from an excel spreadsheet. One solution is to use [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) to remove [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and change line endings from CRLF to LF. You can also use sed (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240387/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file), or many other methods to 'reformat' the file

Comment: @jared_mamrot Wow, that is well spotted. If the input lines end in \r\n that explains the results perfectly.